# Treating nils in sort function

Tags: sorting, lua, null, lua-table

I don't know how to handle `nils` my sort function gets.

When I have this checking in it, `table.sort` crashes after some calls.

```
if a == nil then
    return false
elseif b == nil then
    return true
end
```

With this error:**invalid order function for sorting**. But according to the documentation, sort function should return false, if a goes after b. True otherwise.

If I remove remove that code, it of course crashes of indexing nils.

Comment: You should post more code. Getting nils in your compare function is fishy. Are you sure the problem is there and not somewhere around?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has little or nothing to do with `nil` values in the table. The error message is generated if the comparison function itself is invalid. From the documentation for [`table.sort`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.sort):

> If `comp` is given, then it must be a
>   function that receives two table
>   elements, and returns true when the
>   first is less than the second (so that
>   `not comp(a[i+1],a[i])` will be true
>   after the sort).

In other words, `comp(a,b)` must imply `not comp(b,a)`. If this relation does not hold, then the error "invalid order function for sorting" will likely raised. (Note that it might not be raised in all cases.)

In order to be more helpful, we really need to see the whole function passed to `table.sort`.

Comment: +1: After testing the code from the question, it does handle nil values in an array correctly.  The problem must be inconsistency in the remainder of the function.

Comment: It should be emphasised that "comp(a,b) -> !comp(b,a)" holds and "comp(a,b) == !comp(b,a)" does not; as in the case of a==b, where the function would return false for both calls to comp().

Answer (score 2):

To put all nil values at the beginning of the array:

```
  function mycomp(a,b)
    if a == nil and b == nil then
      return false
    end
    if a == nil then
      return true
    end
    if b == nil then
      return false
    end
    return a < b
  end
```

To put all nil values at the end of the array:

```
function mycomp(a,b)
  if a == nil and b == nil then
    return false
  end
  if a == nil then
    return false
  end
  if b == nil then
    return true
  end
  return a < b
end
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't explained myself well enough: First, THERE'S NO NIL IN TABLE. Second, table.sort doesn't want to have so many conditions there clearly, because when I remove nil checking it continues, but crashes o nil.