# Corona table.sort()

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local tile = {"C", "O", "L", "I", "N", "F", "A", "R", "R", "E", "L", "L"}       
table.sort(tile, function(a,b) return ( math.random(1,2) <2) end)
print ( 'table: '..table.concat( tile, ', '))
```

I am randomizing the order of the table, which seems to work fine, but every 2nd time I run the program I get this error : `invalid order function for sorting`. Any suggestions as to what is happening?

I have found the solution to this.
http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/shufflerandomize-tables
This will shuffle the contents of your table without any of the problems of the method above.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102710/treating-nils-in-sort-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to shuffle an array, take a look at [my shuffle snippet](http://snippets.luacode.org/snippets/Shuffle_array_145).

The main idea is that you create a table of items with random numbers, sort that while keeping the original index, and reorder the items according to the new order.

```
function shuffled(tab)
    local n, order, res = #tab, {}, {}
    for i=1,n do order[i] = { rnd = math.random(), idx = i } end
    table.sort(order, function(a,b) return a.rnd < b.rnd end)
    for i=1,n do res[i] = tab[order[i].idx] end
    return res
end
```

Comment: Now when I think of it, [Fisher-Yates](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/shufflerandomize-tables) is probably much more efficient...

Answer (score 1):

The sort function given to `table.sort` is assumed to be deterministic in the sense that it always returns the same result for the same pair of arguments, and consistent, in the sense that `a<b` and `b<c` implies `a<c`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Gooner, which problem? The function you gave to `table.sort`*is* invalid.

Comment: I don't really understand how it works, is there a way to randomize the elements of a table, which will work every time it is used?

Comment: @Gooner, please ask a separate question on how to randomize a table.

Comment: Its ok, I found what I needed. I posted a link in my original question